# Read "smbstatus --shares" data from application

Tags: server, samba, application-development

I want to create an application that shows who is connected to the samba server.

How can I read `--shares data`.
Where is that data located?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Samba4.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo smbstatus` to show the shares and who / what is connected.

Example:

```
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo smbstatus

Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
651248  nobody       nogroup      10.0.0.100 (ipv4:10.0.0.100:51922)        SMB3_11           -                    -    

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
storage      651248  10.0.0.100    Sat Sep  4 10:24:44 AM 2021 MDT  -            -
IPC$         651248  10.0.0.100    Sat Sep  4 10:24:41 AM 2021 MDT  -            -

Locked files:
Pid          User(ID)   DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
651248       65534      DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/storage   Disney Parks   Sat Sep  4 10:24:45 2021
651248       65534      DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/storage   Disney Parks   Sat Sep  4 10:24:45 2021
651248       65534      DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/storage   .   Sat Sep  4 10:24:43 2021
651248       65534      DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/storage   .   Sat Sep  4 10:24:43 2021
651248       65534      DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/storage   .   Sat Sep  4 10:24:43 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist anywhere except in your terminal but you can send the output to a file if you want:

```
sudo smbstatus --shares > /path/to/file
```